# Add css to button

Tags: html, css, button

how could add css style to this button.
Button html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Player</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert('what ever');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS i want to add

```
<style>
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

If there is answered question, please send link. Thank you

Comment: have you not tried adding a css class to the button? or setting a button definition in the css? or adding the css directly to the button?

Comment: Either change `.button` to `button` in your CSS, or add `class="button"` to your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `class="button"` to the button to make it work. Cause your CSS `.button` will be used on every element which has the `class="button"`

```js
 function myFunction() {
    alert('what ever')
 }
```

```css
.button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Player</button>
```

[Read more about how CSS Selectors work here](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Player</button>
```

As your button class you've set it ".button" add "button" as a class like above
Anything you put after the . will match the name of the class in the element

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/ explains how you use classes, ids and what they do in good detail

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring class button i.e(.button) you can apply style to all button elements.

Demo- https://jsfiddle.net/akshay193sw/bxm8wdqk/ `Refer link`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you're two solutions :

**First** :  use classe, if you've differents buttons in your pages : 
you can just add `class` attribute in your HTML element like that :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Player</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert('what ever');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And define the style in your class in your CSS :

```
<style>
.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

**Second** : If all buttons are the same style, you can just add style for all element `button` :

Not change your HTML :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Player</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert('what ever');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, in your CSS, just change the reference, for select elements `button` :

```
<style>
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

You can learn more explain about selector (`.myClass`, `#myId`, `element`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) in the mozilla developper website.

Don't forget, for optimize your web code, use as little code as possible, for reduce weight of pages, and to correctly use the different selectors (classes or id as not mandatory for CSS style : that depend to your utility) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style a button I recommend adding a class to it and styling it with CSS. Here is an example below.

HTML Below

`<button class='button_thing'> My Button </button>`

CSS Below

```
.button_thing {
background-color: blue;
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

So what the CSS and HTML code above will do is it will create a blue button with a curved border and with a height of 100 pixels and width of 180 pixels. Now, the next question you might ask is how do I make an animation on the button when I hover over it?

CSS Hover Animations are a bit tricky at the start but get easier with practice. When I make buttons for my websites I like to use a site called ButtonAnimations because it gets straight to the point and gives me tons of animations (with HTML & CSS code) to choose from. Totally recommend it because it simply provides you with amazing buttons and animations that you can just copy and paste into your code. ButtonAnimations Website Link: [ButtonAnimations - Create Spectacular Button Animations with HTML 7 CSS](https://buttonanimations.github.io/)